# How to make a clickable element that fits perfectly into text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently writing a full-javascript application based on ascii art. There will be big pieces of ascii art, and I need to make clickable parts of this ascii art. Problem is : the ascii art is monospaced, of course, so the clickable part must fit perfectly inside the art and musn't break the alignment of the art's characters.

When I use a button like that :

```
<button style="border:none; font-familiy:monospace"></button>
```

Then the alignment is broken, and the result varies depending on the browser.

So I could use a span and make it clickable using javascript, but I heard that it wasn't a good idea for accessibility to do so... what's the best solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: Well first you need to spell family correct.

Comment: What's wrong with an anchor tag?

Comment: Are you removing padding, margins, borders, setting correct line heights, and all of that wonderful stuff. Why not use an anchor to eliminate most of that setting?

Comment: Html : <button class="asciiButton">my button</button>
Css :
.asciiButton{
    font-family: monospace; /* Same font family as the ascii art in the <pre> tags */
    border: 0;
    background: none;
}

Answer (score 1):

You could remove all the styles from the button like background, border, padding, margin, etc.

Regarding accessibility, what would be so bad about using onclick on a span, or maybe an `a` tag?